# @viewchildren not working if element availalbe in child component

Tags: angular

Let say i have "ParentComponent"

**ParentComponent.html**

```
<div>
  <child1></child>
</div>
```

**Child1.html**

```
<h1 #childH1>
  Ezzy
</h1>
```

now if we are accessing "childH1" from "parentComponent.ts" then it is not accessible if we are using by @viewchildren/@viewchild.

Comment: Can you provide more context? What does "not accessible" mean? Is there any error message involved?

Answer (score 0):

Put #childH1 in parent template:

```
  <child1 #childH1></child>
```

Comment: If you need an other template variable to use in child component, you still can create it <h1 #h1>
  Ezzy
</h1>

Answer (score 0):

Reference #childH1 should be in parent child tab 
ParentComponent.html

```
<div>
  <child1 #childH1></child>
</div>
Child1.html

<h1 >
  Ezzy
</h1>
```

Comment: but i need #childH1 in child and want to access from parent